# Definition of "ceci fait que"

Tags: sens, expressions

I couldn't find any translations on WordReference of Google. I know "ceci" means this, but I couldn't find a definition for "fait que". Would the whole phrase mean "this makes"?

Comment: There is no literal translation. See all the French/English examples here: http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/ceci+fait+que.html

Comment: You should add the context. "Ceci fait que" is not a whole sentence, so it's harder to help you without the context.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as meaning "*this **has the effect that***", which is almost a literal translation.  "Faire" and "have the effect" have the same origin, and the latter is about the only English verb form I can think of that is related to "faire".  (There are lots of English nouns that are related: manufacture ("fait à la main"), feat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Ceci fait que" is an idiom used to connect two statements, explicitly making the one following "ceci/cela fait que" a consequence of the one preceding it, e.g.:

> Nous n'avons plus d'argent; ceci fait que nous n'irons pas en vacances cette année.

Which could be translated to:

> We no longer have money therefore we won't go on vacation this year.

It is synonymous with "ce qui fait que".

> Nous n'avons plus d'argent, ce qui fait que nous n'irons pas en vacances cette année.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular construction, *faire* happens to mean, er... "to mean", so the expression translates to *this means that*, which is a commonplace expression in English.

If you wanted to go REALLY literal, you could translate it as *this makes it so that*.

Comment: Je pense qu'il faut aussi préciser que fait que introduit une conséquence, c'est souvent rendu en anglais par *this implies*, *as a result*, etc...

Comment: It's hard to assume "to mean" while there is absolutely no context specified.